# accessing elements of json array in php

Tags: php, json

Hi I have the following json:

```
{"@attributes":{"Version":"2.0"},"METADATA":{"FIELDS":{"FIELD":[{"@attributes":{"attrname":"street1","fieldtype":"string","width":"50"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"town","fieldtype":"string","width":"50"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"addresscode","fieldtype":"i4"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"personcode","fieldtype":"i4"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"Forename","fieldtype":"string","width":"15"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"Surname","fieldtype":"string","width":"20"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"Phone","fieldtype":"string","width":"30"}},{"@attributes":{"attrname":"Phone2","fieldtype":"string","width":"30"}}]},"PARAMS":{"@attributes":{"DEFAULT_ORDER":"1","PRIMARY_KEY":"1","LCID":"1033"}}},"ROWDATA":{"ROW":[{"@attributes":{"street1":"x House ","town":"town1","addresscode":"xxx","personcode":"yyy","Forename":"John","Surname":"Doe","Phone2":"087 123 4567"}},{"@attributes":{"street1":"street2 ","town":"town2","addresscode":"zzz","personcode":"ppp","Forename":"Jane","Surname":"Doe","Phone":"0831234567"}}]}}
```

And I have been unable trying to parse it, I am getting an error of:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

Code below:

```
$filename = 'C:/myfile.xml'; 
$Users = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$JSON_Users = json_encode($Users);
$jfo = json_decode($JSON_Users);
$UsersParsed = $jfo->ROWDATA->ROW;

foreach ($UsersParsed as $user) {

    $FName = $user->@attributes->Forename;
    $SName = $user->@attributes->Surname;
    echo $FName.' and '.$SName.'<br>';

}
```

I tried without the @ symbol and got an error of:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$attributes
```

Any help appreciated

/**EDITED JSON**/ Apologies

Comment: Wait why did this get 2 downvotes?

Comment: @Loko would be great if people commented on why they have down voted

Comment: I agree. You're giving enough information to solve this problem(I think). Maybe people actually downvote it because it's an easy question for them? Really weird downvotes.

Comment: Probably because that's not valid JSON to begin with, and you should really start to solve your problem by fixing that. Use this rather competent linter: http://jsonlint.com/ =)

Comment: @J. Steen Thanks for your comment. Ok well perhaps I haven't pasted it all in correctly as I was trying to cut out all the unnecessary but the entire JSON is valid according to JSONlint anyway

Comment: Then paste a **valid** json-snippet in your question. Also - why tag this as XML? Basically, all this erroneous information is probably confusing people and therefore this question is marked as "not useful" or "lacks research effort".

Comment: @J. Steen Apologies, I obviously was unaware I pasted an invalid JSON, (unintentional) See edited question. I just tagged xml as the file is originally xml before I convert to JSON

Comment: @J.Steen Aha well the question looked good from my point of view.(No experience in json at all)

Comment: @J. Steen any advice on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This way it returns an array instead of an object and after you change the way you access its content everything goes smooth:

```
$filename = 'C:/myfile.xml'; 
$Users = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$JSON_Users = json_encode($Users);
$jfo = json_decode($JSON_Users, TRUE);
$UsersParsed = $jfo['ROWDATA']['ROW'];

foreach ($UsersParsed as $user) {

    $FName = $user['@attributes']['Forename'];
    $SName = $user['@attributes']['Surname'];
    echo $FName.' and '.$SName.'<br>';

}
```

Another solution is to use the [correct syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) to access the properties of objects when they contain characters not allowed in variable names (because, for example, they were created by conversion and not using the regular way):

```
foreach ($UsersParsed as $user) {

    $FName = $user->{'@attributes'}->Forename;
    $SName = $user->{'@attributes'}->Surname;
    echo $FName.' and '.$SName.'<br>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. It's working now. Also good to know that the @ symbols were generated as the json was created by converting from XML

Answer (score 2):

`@` is an reserved operator in PHP and can not be part of a variable name. It suppresses the standard error output.

To address object properties with characters that are not allowed in variable names use the `{'name'}` syntax.

```
$FName = $user->{'@attributes'}->Forename;
```

Note: Using SimpleXML together with XPath or even DOM+XPath, is a lot more efficient.